# Linux lagging/freezing when not idle, with 100% disk read usage

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, lag

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. When my PC is idle, I get around 0-2% usage of disk I/O, but immediately after I start doing things like clicking on a web browser or e.g. Atom editor, the *read* operation occupies disk 100%. Even a simple application like gedit makes it jump to 75%. There doesn't seem to be any reading/writing errors, the reading just takes up the whole bandwidth. Could this indicate hard drive problems and if so, how to proceed?

Comment: Look into `dmesg` to see if there are any read/write errors for your disk(s). Use `iotop` etc. to find out if there are other process(es) responsible.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I did check for errors in `dmesg` and there are none, also `iotop` and similar apps don't show anything suspicious.

Comment: Next thing I'd do is look at SMART data (`smartctl`) for anything suspicious. Where do you read off those disk I/O percentages, BTW? If 100% just mean "read works at full speed", that isn't a bad thing ... if the operation takes longer than it should, it isn't.